# Has custom icon behaviour changed with JQueryMobile 1.4 (Alpha / Beta / RC-1)?

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-mobile

I've had a section of script that worked with JQueryMobile 1.3 and earlier, in which I use a custom icon (national flags) to decorate a language selection button.

With the new 1.4 release, the icons no longer show

Does anyone know if this is a design change - and if so provide me some hints as to how to change the syntax to get the icons to show up again? I quite like the new version, so it'd be a shame to not upgrade to it.

If not, I guess it is an introduced bug?

I specify the flags and their location in the css - example;

```
.ui-icon-arabic-flag {
background-image: url("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/47293334/flags/flag-icon-arabic.png");}
```

You can see JSFiddle examples here (both using JQuery 1.9.1);

Script, using JQueryMobile 1.3 framework (All working);
[Working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vinomarky/QBW2Z/1/)

And identical script using JQueryMobile 1.4B1 framework (Icons dont show up)
[Not Working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vinomarky/EjJy9/1/)

Comment: I'm not sure whether this is the cause, but you might want to take a look at https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/6272?source=cc

Comment: Data-role=button, data-icon are deprecated as well as .buttonMarkup(). Anchors now get enhanced without data-role=button and icons are added as classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered by Jasper de Groot,and confirmed by me that it works;

"It still works but you have to use
:after
in your selector. See http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0-rc.1/dist/demos/icons/#CustomIcons"